# Dynamically bootstrapping Bare-Metal Nodes to Chef during Kickstart Post Script

Tags: centos, chef-infra

I'm working on some automation to build my bare-metal hosts.  The automation goes through a kickstart script to install CentOS 7.3, wrapping up by running some post-kickstart install scripts.  One of these scripts does the necessary work to install the Chef package, copy over the certs I need, generate the appropriate files, join the node the the org, place it in an appropriate environment and role and then finally run a chef-client.

Everything seems to be working up until I get to the point where I run my chef-client --once command, which is failing on its first run.  When I manually login to the box after the fact and run a manual chef-client, I have no issue, runs just fine. The only thing in my run-list is chef-client::default and chef-client::config.  Chef Version 19.33.36.

Here is the snippet of bash code where I am bootstrapping to my org and then running chef-client:

```
cd /opt/chef/bin/
chef-client -c /etc/chef/client.rb
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log
echo "chef-client -c /etc/chef/client.rb" >> /tmp/build.log
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log

(cd /etc/chef && /usr/bin/knife node environment set $HOST $CHEF_ENV)
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log
echo "/usr/bin/knife node environment set $HOST $CHEF_ENV" >> /tmp/build.log
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log

(cd /etc/chef && /usr/bin/knife node run_list set $HOST role[$CHEF_ROLE])
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log
echo "/usr/bin/knife node run_list set $HOST role[$CHEF_ROLE]" >> 
/tmp/build.log
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log

CHEF_RUN_OUTPUT=`chef-client --once`
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log
echo "chef-client --once" >> /tmp/build.log
echo "---------------------------------------" >> /tmp/build.log
echo $CHEF_RUN_OUTPUT >> /tmp/build.log
```

Here is the log of what is occurring after my post script finishes:

From /var/log/chef/client.log:

```
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/run/chef] action create (chef-client::systemd_service line 56)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/run/chef] created directory /var/run/chef
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/run/chef] owner changed to 0
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/run/chef] group changed to 0
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/cache/chef] action create (chef-client::systemd_service line 56)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/cache/chef] created directory /var/cache/chef
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/cache/chef] owner changed to 0
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/cache/chef] group changed to 0
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/lib/chef] action create (chef-client::systemd_service line 56)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/lib/chef] created directory /var/lib/chef
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/lib/chef] owner changed to 0
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: directory[/var/lib/chef] group changed to 0
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/log/chef] action create (chef-client::systemd_service line 56)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing directory[/etc/chef] action create (chef-client::systemd_service line 56)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing template[/etc/sysconfig/chef-client] action create (chef-client::systemd_service line 27)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/chef-client] created file /etc/sysconfig/chef-client
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/chef-client] updated file contents /etc/sysconfig/chef-client
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/chef-client] mode changed to 644
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing systemd_unit[chef-client.service] action create (chef-client::systemd_service line 56)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing file[/etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service] action create (dynamically defined)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: template[/etc/sysconfig/chef-client] sending restart action to service[chef-client] (delayed)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Processing service[chef-client] action restart (chef-client::systemd_service line 62)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: service[chef-client] restarted
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 2a04bb13-bd0e-4fec-b6e0-093bd0bb3ab7)
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] ERROR: systemd_unit[chef-client.service] (chef-client::systemd_service line 56) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: file[/etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service] (dynamically defined) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Proposed content for /etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service failed verification #<Chef::Resource::File::Verification:0x000000028b2200>
  [2017-08-18T10:51:51-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

From the chef-stacktrace.out:

```
>>>> Caused by Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Proposed content for /etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service failed verification #<Chef::Resource::File::Verification:0x000000028b2200>
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:352:in `block in do_validate_content'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:350:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:350:in `do_validate_content'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:151:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource.rb:622:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:198:in `manage_unit_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:60:in `block in action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider.rb:176:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:59:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource.rb:622:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/runner.rb:69:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:114:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:103:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/runner.rb:96:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/client.rb:670:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/client.rb:665:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/client.rb:665:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/client.rb:704:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/client.rb:284:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application.rb:295:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application.rb:283:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application.rb:283:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application.rb:248:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application/client.rb:464:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application/client.rb:451:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application/client.rb:434:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.33/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:57:in `load'
```

Adding in the chef-client -l debug level logs for further analysis:

```
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: Initiating POST to https://chef001/organizations/baremetal-sh-npe/reports/nodes/node/runs/61604df2-38ea-4d3d-9be3-3d93ef8187bc
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-Ops-Reporting-Protocol-Version: 0.1.0
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: Content-Encoding: gzip
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-Ops-Server-API-Version: 1
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-SIGN: algorithm=sha1;version=1.1;
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-USERID: t9301bmh1001
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-TIMESTAMP: 2017-08-23T16:11:19Z
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-CONTENT-HASH: khFZ3GcjogWXzfxs5/c8VQOIK/0=
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-1: A3v+4H3vj4baFTprTLXLW9rEUP5qOSu95VC3oXJi8A0GUPqP8D1JK+Fn4C/k
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-2: Mksf+LkEIyV+RpNZ/qoRUFeKk90HIViK6+bU31GAkZLArr0aNJHEaBQTOmq7
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-3: zEWHWKHPDdw7coQ4VSi/uqQML20K2fSB5e5mRffnqdHu8cYafmzOEXM/dBcR
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-4: ozK/ATHfxqK/h3PpEdetfNDRsoLF3z2dsNeBepArtOkpVbi900UkANib1CFD
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-5: K4nMY8HbS6SLAjzwZR9+k6WojXwM5Ea5w5o5QKfAvLyAvQJjjOBRh1IIPC+m
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-6: mnggHfPZWY3Nat12n6DVR/dFz+xStrPe7P799ZHivA==
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: HOST: chef001.target.com:443
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: X-REMOTE-REQUEST-ID: 61604df2-38ea-4d3d-9be3-3d93ef8187bc
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: Content-Length: 2092
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 200 OK
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: server: openresty/1.11.2.1
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 16:11:19 GMT
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: content-type: application/json
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: content-length: 2
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: connection: close
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: Audit Reports are disabled. Skipping sending reports.
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] DEBUG: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: systemd_unit[chef-client.service] (chef-client::systemd_service line 56) had an         error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: file[/etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service] (dynamically defined) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Valida        tionFailed: Proposed content for /etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service failed verification #<Chef::Resource::File::Verification:0x000000063fa808>
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:352:in `block in do_validate_content'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:350:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:350:in `do_validate_content'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:151:in `action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource.rb:622:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:198:in `manage_unit_file'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:60:in `block in action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider.rb:176:in `converge_by'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:59:in `action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource.rb:622:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:69:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:114:in `call_iterator_block'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:103:in `iterate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:96:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:670:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:665:in `catch'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:665:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:704:in `converge_and_save'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:284:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:295:in `block in fork_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:283:in `fork'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:283:in `fork_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:248:in `block in run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:464:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:451:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `loop'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `interval_run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:434:in `run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:57:in `load'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:57:in `<main>'

  >>>> Caused by Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Proposed content for /etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service failed verification #<Chef::Resource::        File::Verification:0x000000063fa808>
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:352:in `block in do_validate_content'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:350:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:350:in `do_validate_content'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:151:in `action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource.rb:622:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:198:in `manage_unit_file'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:60:in `block in action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider.rb:176:in `converge_by'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider/systemd_unit.rb:59:in `action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource.rb:622:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:69:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:114:in `call_iterator_block'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:103:in `iterate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/runner.rb:96:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:670:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:665:in `catch'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:665:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:704:in `converge_and_save'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/client.rb:284:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:295:in `block in fork_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:283:in `fork'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:283:in `fork_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:248:in `block in run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:464:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:451:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `loop'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:450:in `interval_run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application/client.rb:434:in `run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:57:in `load'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:57:in `<main>'
  [2017-08-23T11:11:19-05:00] ERROR: systemd_unit[chef-client.service] (chef-client::systemd_service line 56) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Validation        Failed: file[/etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service] (dynamically defined) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Proposed content for /et        c/systemd/system/chef-client.service failed verification #<Chef::Resource::File::Verification:0x000000063fa808>
  [2017-08-23T11:11:20-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Any thoughts on why my first run is going south? My intention is to have the node placed in it's appropriate env and role, and then for the box to run all the appropriate recipes associated with the env/role.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the full path, but just use `knife bootstrap` and it will take care of this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please?  knife bootstrap in what way?    What is the proper path to run chef-client from?   /opt/chef/bin or usr/bin/chef-client?  Thanks!

Comment: Hey -  I looked at the Knife bootstrap piece, it doesn't look like that would work for me since I have my host dynamically bootstrapping itself rather than me running a command to bootstrap a set of nodes manually.  I'm testing with the full pathing you suggested now.

Comment: If you are doing an auto-scaling type workflow, you wouldn't use knife to set initial data like that, it goes in the `-j` initial JSON fed to chef-client for the first run.

Comment: Tried both /opt/chef/bin/chef-client and /usr/bin/chef-client, same error both ways.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: K, I'll try using the json file.  Thanks sir!

Comment: The path issue is just the most common systemd unit validation failure. Unfortunately you would have to turn the log level up to debug to see the actual error message given by systemctl.

Comment: Elevate client.log to debug?

Comment: Using chef-client -j runlist.json actually is producing the same set of error messages....with only chef-client::default and chef-client::config in the run list.